Vue 3. Асинхронная функция не завершает выполнение в хуке onMounted при использование await
onMounted(async () => {
try {
    if (chosenRealty.value) {
        // асинхронная функция возвращает promise (если вывести результат в console.log)
        await getPayments()
        // асинхронная функция возвращает promise (если вывести результат в console.log)
        await getServices()
    }
} catch (error) {
    throw error
}

})
** Если убрать ключенвое слово await перед getPayments() то все работает корректно. При этом если выводить результат выполнения getPayments() в console.log() то выводиться Promise **
const getPayments = async () => {
try {
    const res = await store.dispatch('realties/fetchPayments', {
        page: lastSelectionPage.value,
        service_id: selectedService.value,
        organization_id: selectedOrganizations.value,
        status: statuses[selectedStatus.value]?.id,
        date_start: timestampStart.value,
        date_end: timestampEnd.value
    })
    paymentsData.value = res.data.data
    paymentsPagination.value = res.data.pagination

    loading.value = false

    return res
} catch (error) {
    throw error
}

}

Вполне возможно, что getPayments не разрешается. Вот ты и "висишь" вечно на await getPayments()...
